# How to remove the same row location from multiple vectors?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have `n` number of vectors (single column), which are correlated.  One of them (let's say the first of the `n` vectors) has a bunch of `NaN`s in it.  I have used the `erase - remove_if` idiom to clear this vector of the rows which contain the `NaN`s.  I want to remove the exact same row from all the other vectors either simultaneously or after the fact.  This seems like it would be a common coding problem, but I can't find an example.  I'm coding in C++, with OpenCV libraries.

Here is my code sample that doesn't work, which I think is kind of what Miki is suggesting

```
vector<float> RemoveManyEs(vector<float> &V1, vector<float> &V2, vector<float> &V3)
{
    int length = V1.size();
    int n = 0;
    do
    {
        if (isnan(V1.at(n)))
        {
            V1.erase(V1.begin() + n);
            V2.erase(V2.begin() + n);
            V3.erase(V3.begin() + n);
        }
        n += 1;
    } while (n < length);
return V1,V2,V3;
```

}

Comment: If the vectors must remain in lockstep, why have other vectors?

Comment: Just scan your first vector (or the one containing the NaNs), and store the indices of the NaNs. Then, remove from each vector the elements at the retrieved indices.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to put my example code in this comment to continue discussion

Comment: test `vector<float>`....not quite

Comment: test {vector<float>}...nope

Comment: @Clay: Why not edit the question instead?

Comment: Ok.  Put my example code in an edit of question.  The example code crashes when I run it

Comment: Problem solved.  I need an "else" statement in that code, to iterate n+=1, instead of on outside of if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether or not you really need to delete the rows or whether it would suffice to set them to zero. If less than 10% of the rows need to be deleted, then removing them would have a negligible effect on run-time (and could even make things take longer overall after the overhead of reallocation).

If you are computing correlation matrices for example, then you'll get the same result by zeroing out all elements. This is generally a much simpler operation and will give you the result you need for most applications.